# How to numpy-ify a two dimensional conditional lookup?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to vectorize or otherwise make faster (likely using numpy) a lookup/matching for loop. I've looked into `np.vectorize`, numpy indexing and `np.where`, but can't find the right implementation/combination to fit my needs.

Code in Question:

```
Sx = np.zeros((Np+1, 2*N+1))
rows, cols = prepped_array.shape[0], prepped_array.shape[1]

for ind1 in range(rows):
    for ind2 in range(cols):
        if prepped_array[ind1][ind2][0] != -1:
            Sx[ind1, ind2] = M[prepped_array[ind1][ind2][0], prepped_array[ind1][ind2][1]]
```

`prepped_array` is a lookup table (initialized to all `[-1, -1]`) where values have been replaced where they should be changed in `Sx`.

`M` is transformed input that we want to map into the `Sx` array.

Any ideas/pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask for indexing the `Sx` and `prepped_array` and then use two index arrays, derived from the `prepped_array`, to index into the `M` array. The code might speak clearer than the previous sentence:

```
mask = prepped_array[:, :, 0] != -1
Sx[mask] = M[tuple(prepped_array[mask].T)]
```

Let's look at the involved steps:

- `mask = prepped_array[:, :, 0] != -1` creates a 2D boolean array indicating where the condition is met.
- `prepped_array[mask]` creates a 2D array where entries from the previous 3rd dimensions appear now along the 2nd dimension; the first dimensions corresponds to each `True` instance in `mask`.
- `tuple(prepped_array[mask].T)` creates two 1D arrays which can be used to further index into other arrays: the first array denotes row indices and the second array denotes column indices.
- So `Sx[mask] = M[tuple(prepped_array[mask].T)]` maps the indices contained in `prepped_array` to the array `M` using the previous two 1D index arrays.
- `Sx[mask]` finally references those elements in `Sx` that for which the condition in `prepped_array[:, :, 0]` is met.